# How to make the database delete a row after certain time on the row?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm doing a project about reporting situations on a map. Each report is marked by a pin on the map. The `pin` table has an attribute, `report_time`, that saves the hour in which the pin was inserted (or in which the report was made).

How can I make a function/trigger/procedure (whatever is the best option) to delete that row after 15 minutes since the report? I want something on my database that gets the `report_time` and deletes the row if 15 minutes have passed.

Comment: you have to write a scheduler for it. What is you OS

Comment: i'm using Windows and the database is Postgresql

Answer (score 2):

Instead of constantly deleting rows, how about just using a view?

```
create view v_pin as
    select p.*
    from pin p
    where p.report_time > now() - interval '15 minute;
```

Anyone who uses the view will only see the most recent rows.

Then, when the database is quiescent or when you want -- say once an hour or once a day or once a week, just schedule a job to remove old rows:

```
delete from pin
    where report_time < now() - interval '15 minute';
```

What is elegant about this solution is that users will never see inappropriate rows in the table, even if the job does not run as scheduled or the table is locked for updates for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for answearing but we can't do that on this project because all the data (pins) from the table are being shown live on the map of the App we are developing... :/

Comment: @Enguias . . . I don't understand.   You can just use the view to populate the map.

Comment: Seemly the only reason you can't do as @GordonLinoff suggests is that you do not control the query populating the map. But the same can be achieved: rename the table (say pin_tbl) then recreate pin as the view. Your App will be non the wiser and as long as it's simple view it's updateable directly (no instead of trigger as needed) if that is part of the app.